# Parsing mIRC colors in php

Tags: php, colors, mirc

I want to convert [mirc color codes](http://www.mirc.com/help/colors.html) to html via php.
Here is the example: `http://searchirc.com/search.php?F=exact&T=chan&N=6246&I=anime-pirates`

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything I understand in your linked example. Can you describe how the colour codes work?

Comment: http://www.mirc.com/help/colors.html please take a look at it.
Basicly, after the "ctrl + k" combination we type a number for each color. If we use comma between to numbers, we get background...

Comment: What do you want to parse? What form will the data be coming in? What is the input source/method? How does the PHP need set up? Will you be using preset HTML classes or just setting the background color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback):

```
function mycallback($matches) {
    $bindings = array(
       0=>'white',
       1=>'black',
       2=>'blue',
       3=>'green',
       4=>'red',
       5=>'brown',
       6=>'purple',
    );

    $fg = isset($bindings[$matches[1]]) ? $bindings[$matches[1]] : 'transparent';
    $bg = isset($bindings[$matches[2]]) ? $bindings[$matches[2]] : 'transparent';

    return '<span style="color: '.$fg.'; background: '.$bg.';">'.$matches[3].'</span>';
}

$str = '^C3,1Hello^C foo ^C6,2World^C';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\^C([0-9]{1,2}),?([0-9]{1,2})(.*?)\^C/', 'mycallback', $str);

echo $str;
```