# HTML: Closing multiple tags with just a single tag

Tags: php, html

I have a log file that has ANSI colors. I use PHP to str_replace these into `<span color="">` HTML tags.

If I use PHP str_replace, and parse color resets as `</span>`, how would I end more than one span declaration?

Example: `<span color="red"><span color="blue"></span>`

How could I make it so that one `</span>` ends both the previous  statements?

Comment: No `</span>` will ever close more than one `<span>`

Comment: You can't close two elements with one closing tag.

Comment: when did span get an attribute "color"

Comment: You might find the following question interesting: [Mirc control codes to html, through php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329443/mirc-control-codes-to-html-through-php/10330451#10330451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't, you need to use two `</span></span>` tags to close both `<span>` tags.

For your case this would be

```
<span color="red"><span color="blue"></span></span>
```

**Note:** *As @calvinf pointed out in a comment below you should use `style="color:blue;"` since the `color` attribute has been deprecated for a long time.*

Comment: You can count all you like in php, this makes no difference to the html though.  The browser will need the valid html and valid closing tags otherwise it wont know where to end the span.

Comment: Better HTML for this would be: <span style="color:blue;"></span>.  The color attribute has been deprecated for over a decade.

Comment: @calvinf yes, deffinately.  I will edit my answer to include a note about this.

Answer (score 1):

When the browser interprets the `<span>` tag, it expects a closing tag for that Exact Same tag. therefore no matter how many you have open you cannot use a single `</span>` because the browser will be desperately searching for the others.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to that.
I think you have to way to do it,
First mananualy add the missing "`</span>`" which it's a little ugly
Or you could find out why you're missing one